# ''missing number treated as zero'' error in \maketitle

Tags: errors, titles

While writing an article I am getting this error. How do I get rid of it??

[image: image of the error]

The following code reproduces the error message.

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,showkeys,scriptaddress,
groupedaddress,showpacs,onecolumn,
amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=17mm,top=22mm,right=17mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\sloppy
\allowbreak
\date{\today}
\title{title}

\author{author1 \footnote[\P]{$\P$ These authors have contributed equally in 
this paper}}
\email[]{email}
\affiliation{institute}

\author{author2 \footnote[\P]}
\email[]{email}
\affiliation{institute}

\begin{abstract}
abstract
\end{abstract}
\keywords{Entanglement, Deutsch-Jozsa Algorithm, IBM Quantum Experience}

\maketitle
\onecolumngrid
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to LaTeX! Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Welcome, with the information given, we cannot help you. We just don't know what is going on at all. I guess this is based on a journal template? Which one? Can you reproduce the issue with the unmodified template? If not, some of the changes you made are causing the error and we don't know those changes. You need to show them to us, possibly as cmpilable but small code.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: The document you just posted compiles fine on my machine after fixing the obvious not needed `%` signs.

Comment: and adding `\end{document}`

Comment: Apparently, RevTeX does not like `\P` as a footnote number.

Comment: it's necessary for me to have that footnote. what can I do now?

Comment: Unrelated, maybe replace `dirtytalk` by the more famous `csquotes` package.

Answer (score 2):

The following is more of a hacky way to get what you want. Please make sure with the journal editors that this kind of change is allowed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,showkeys,scriptaddress,
groupedaddress,showpacs,onecolumn,
amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=17mm,top=22mm,right=17mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\sloppy
\allowbreak
\date{\today}
\title{Differences between Apples and Oranges}

    \author{Walter Wombat\textsuperscript{\P}\footnotetext{\hspace{-1em}\P These authors have contributed equally in this paper}}
    \email{email of Walter}
    \affiliation{institute of Apples}
    \author{Carl Capybara\textsuperscript{\P}}
    \affiliation{instituteof Oranges}



    \maketitle
    \onecolumngrid
    \section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is a spacing missing in `instituteof Oranges` ;-)

Comment: @Christian I know, didn't bother to get tge quesrion back on main because of an edit.

Comment: There's worse than this question to be bumped to the main page ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the differences between the code you posted and the folloging working MWE:

```
\documentclass[aps,pra,showkeys,scriptaddress,groupedaddress,showpacs,onecolumn,amsmath,amssymb]{revtex4}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=17mm,top=22mm,right=17mm,bottom=15mm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\sloppy
\allowbreak
\date{\today}
\title{title}

\author{author}
\email[]{email}
\affiliation{institute}

\begin{abstract}
%abstract
\end{abstract}
\keywords{Entanglement, Deutsch-Jozsa Algorithm, IBM Quantum Experience}

\maketitle
\onecolumngrid
\section{Introduction} 
\end{document}
```

The following is the `diff` of the two MWEs (only different rows are shown):

```
\title{%title}                            | \title{title}
\author{%author}                          | \author{author}
\email[]{%email}                          | \email[]{email}
\affiliation{%institute}                  | \affiliation{institute}
                                          > \end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The error cannot be reproduced with the given code. All this answer does is saying: Works for me. Which could have easily been a comment.

Comment: the code _as given by the OP_ by its edit to the question does not work. But we know how to fix it. So I highlighted the differences by posting the output of a diff of his code and a fixed version of the same.